# Background task and duration (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, background-agents

I've read a lot of different values for how long a background task can run. Everything from 15 to 30 seconds. [MSDN writes 25 seconds.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Does anyone know what the value is for sure? If the value is 25 seconds does it mean that I have 25 seconds to perform my tasks or does the task take some time to start and/or finish?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN seems like it's been updated, as I could swear that it was 15 seconds earlier this year. Anyway, I wouldn't concern myself, because if you can't do the operation in 15 seconds, you're likely to break the memory limit of 5 MB as well.

Also, the time is the execution time from when the [ScheduledTaskAgent.OnInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledtaskagent.oninvoke%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) is called.

Comment: The article says it was updated september 23. My code finishes in a second but my the HTTPWebRequest sometimes takes 20 seconds because of a slow/overloaded server and that is the my problem. Thats why it would be great to know for sure if I have 15 or 25 seconds. This is all so confusing :)

Comment: It's 25 if the documentation says so. If you don't believe the documentation, write a test :p

Comment: Either way, plan on using a timeout on the webrequest. If you cant finish it in ~15, bail early so you don't have your Agent failing all the time.

Comment: Isn't sending a Toast Notification will help in your situation where you don't have to make an explicit webrequest ?